# How can I make the user confirm their current password when using has_secure_password?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passwords

I want the user to successfully confirm their current password in order to change their password.  I initially had something on the controller#update, but it seems that adding an error to a virtual attribute does not make an instance invalid as the save was not prevented.

I am using has_secure_password.  I've now switched to a validation in the model, but the code below always fails to validate because authenticate is returning false.  I did some testing in console and found that if I did

```
user = User.first
user.current_password = 'thecurrentpassword'
user.password = 'thenewpassword'
user.valid?  => false
user.authenticate('thecurrentpassword') => false
user.authenticate('thenewpassword') => true ... before saving
```

So it seems that the password_digest is reset on assignment of a new password instead of the save?  How can I get around this and simply prevent the record from saving if their current_password is wrong, either at the model or controller layer?

```
validate  :validate_current_password, if: Proc.new{ |u| u.persisted? and u.password.present? }

  def validate_current_password
    unless authenticate(current_password)
      errors.add(:current_password, 'invalid password')
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class method something like this:

```
class User
  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    find_by_email(email).try(:authenticate, password)
  end
end
```

Now any controller can find out if a given email + password combination is a valid user.

Comment: Thanks...I'll probably go with this for now, but feel like the validation should be at the model layer.  This approach definitely works though.